# how to pass 2 custom variables to paypal in php

Tags: php, paypal

how to pass 2 custom variables to paypal in php
any one know, help me please.......

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1838585/passing-custom-variables-to-paypal-ipn

Answer (score 0):

According to this thread, it's not officially supported by PayPal: https://www.x.com/message/187862#187862

However, you can implement a workaround by stringing values together and cramming them into the "custom" variable.

Good luck!